# How to get the IP address of localhost?

Tags: apache-httpd

I have a lot of issues getting the IP address of localhost on the server.

I have this status:

```
$ sudo service apache2 status
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2018-04-18 11:44:37 UTC; 18h ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 3087 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3132 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 55
   Memory: 6.0M
      CPU: 53.265s
   CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
           ├─3157 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─3162 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           └─3163 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

Apr 18 11:44:36 instance-3 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
Apr 18 11:44:36 instance-3 apache2[3132]:  * Starting Apache httpd web server apache2
Apr 18 11:44:37 instance-3 apache2[3132]:  *
Apr 18 11:44:37 instance-3 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web server.
Apr 19 03:44:22 instance-3 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web server.
```

When I used:

```
$ curl -4 icanhazip.com
35.197.193.182
```

But then:

```
$ ifconfig
ens4      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 42:01:0a:9a:00:03  
          inet addr:10.154.0.3  Bcast:10.154.0.3  Mask:255.255.255.255
          inet6 addr: fe80::4001:aff:fe9a:3/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1460  Metric:1
          RX packets:4770059 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5014906 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1059058126 (1.0 GB)  TX bytes:1017190807 (1.0 GB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:910501 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:910501 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:153346351 (153.3 MB)  TX bytes:153346351 (153.3 MB)
```

I use `/var/www` and I get success for HTML using the IP starting with `35` but the apps using `localhos`t do not work on the server.

I am unsure what is the actual localhost IP address.

Hosts -

```
>cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
169.254.169.254 metadata.google.internal metadata
10.154.0.3 instance-3.c.inbound-axon-200905.internal instance-3  # Added by Google
169.254.169.254 metadata.google.internal  # Added by Google
```

Comment: Whilst I appreciate all feedback, I do not like my words being changed without even asking me. Some of the changes are subjective and according to someone's own preference.

Comment: Spurious edits can be annoying. Revert them! If you have problems with `localhost`, your `hosts` file may be wrong. Post `cat /etc/hosts`, there should be `localhost` defined there.

Comment: I cannot make head nor tail of the question in _any_ incarnation.  It seems _not_ to be about looking up the IP address of `localhost` _at all_ but about some unspecified "apps" that aren't talking to an HTTP server on the machine, somehow.

Comment: I added the hosts output. About apps etc. I am using apps via browsers which all reference localhost. As the machine is cloud based I have to enter an IP address in the browser and that was the basis of my query. I saw the ifconfig output differs from icanhazip and that is what confused me (and the fact the browser apps are not working).

Comment: What interfaces are your Apache server listening to? There are _three_ IP numbers involved here: 127.0.0.1 (`localhost`, only accessible on the local machine, and your server is not listening to that), 10.154.0.3 (your IP on the local network, not accessible from the public Internet), and 35.197.193.182 (not your machine's IP but probably the IP of a public-facing firewall that passes traffic to your internal machine on 10.154.0.3).

Answer (score 1):

Local host uses a loop back address of 127.0.0.1

From your ifconfig it doesn’t look like that IP is being used on that server.

Try SSH to that IP and see where it’s listed. Although if this is because you’re doing some weird routing or load balancing then you should expand your question to include details of this

Answer (score -1):

Try this solution:

```
ip address show | grep -E "inet " | grep -v "host"
```

Comment: ip address show | grep -E "inet " | grep -v "host"
    inet 10.154.0.3/32 brd 10.154.0.3 scope global ens4

Comment: You saw that the questioner found that IP address in the question, right?